# Prism View Navigation fails on registration name with accent marks

Tags: prism, unity-container

My Prism WPF application (Unity Container) fails to navigate when I use one particular French registration name that has an accent mark.  I'm trying to figure out why and what I can do to fix it.

The English version uses the word "Settings" and works perfectly:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SettingsView>("Settings");
}

public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
{
    regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegion, "Settings");  // THIS WORKS
}
```

The French version uses "Réglages" and fails

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SettingsView>("Réglages");
}
public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
{
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegion, "Réglages");  // FAILS
}
```

The error is an exception in Prism.Unity.Shared/UnityContainerExtension.cs

```
public object Resolve(Type type, string name, params (Type Type, object Instance)[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        var c = _currentScope?.Container ?? Instance;

        // Unity will simply return a new object() for unregistered Views
        if (!c.IsRegistered(type, name))
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"No registered type {type.Name} with the key {name}.");
```

The debugger says that the name that it is looking for is literally `R%C3%A9glages` not `Réglages`

I should note that

- Other French strings (with no accents marks) for other modules navigate just fine so I am guessing this has to do with the accent marks.  But I am not knowledgeable about internationalization so I don't know what to do.  Maybe I need to do something with the code page...?
- My actual application gets these names from language-specific .RESX files.  It doesn't use literals.
- Also I am using Prism.WPF and Prism.Unity version 8.0.0.1909, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism (needlessly) limits the names of views to be able to force the navigation into an uri even on platforms like wpf where it makes no sense at all. So you better stick to plain ASCII strings for your views...

It doesn't make sense to localize internal constants, anyway, to be fair, though.

Comment: Thank you.   I figured it was safe to localize the constant because it only needs to be constant for one run of the application;  That is, changing my app's language setting requires a restart anyway.  But it's good to know I need to be more careful about my registration name.  Still it's a bit difficult to figure out how to to allow a module to "advertise" its localized name to a Prism app that does not know which modules will be there until runtime.  I don't want to force the app to lookup each module's name in a string table because that requires knowing every module type ahead of time.

Comment: You can have a registry where each module registers itself when initialized.